# Consistently scaling and positioning an SVG behind a text grid at different resolutions

Tags: css, svg

As illustrated in the image below, I have some text in a grid (black border) placed on a page (blue border) and an SVG (red border).

The SVG has a number of requirements:

- It needs to be behind the text grid.
- It is larger than the page width and thus needs to be `overflow: hidden` such that width scrollbars do not appear.
- It needs to maintain scale and position relative to the text so the aesthetic is consistent on different viewports, at least at desktop resolutions and ratios.
- Not be `position: fixed`.

I've tried to use the SVG as a `background-image` of the text grid's div which works okay without positioning, however, in order to position the SVG as I'd like, `background-position` and `background-size` are required and it's very difficult to get consistency across different viewport sizes.

I've also tried a separate `div` for the SVG with absolute positioning. However this means that `overflow: hidden` is ignored and thus the width scrollbars.

I'm thinking that the perfect solution doesn't exist unless I develop for specific resolutions and style them individually via media queries.

Any ideas would be appreciated, or at least best practice with sizing and positioning SVG graphics behind elements on a page. Thanks!

Edit: There's an example fiddle to sort of illustrate the problem below - if you make the result window as large as possible and arbitrarily make the browser window different sizes, notice how the SVG has very little consistency in it's position relative to the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/tzge1kwu/4/

[image: Illustration of problem]

Comment: Could you please at least provide some html, a little css and the svg?

Comment: Sure, updated with a link to a fiddle which resembles the problem. Changing the window size dramatically changes the SVG's position.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the problem is? The JSFiddle isn't obviously broken in any way.

Comment: Make the result window as large as possible and then start drastically changing the window size of the tab and see how the SVG loses all sense of consistency in terms of position against the text when the idea is to remain behind the text in a reasonable way. Just looking for a best practice to maintain this

Answer (score 1):

As it happens I encountered this very same issue on the most recent project that I worked on. I don't really know what the best practices are for this problem, but I can tell you what I've worked out.

My technique involves selecting a point on the page and a point in the SVG that I always want to be equal to one another. This way, when the page changes size, these will be locked together and so enforce a degree of visual consistency.

Firstly, I have to work out the point on the page that I want to lock the SVG to, let's call it the *anchor point*. I then position the SVG absolutely and set its `left` and `top` values to be the same as the *x* and *y* values of the anchor point.

I then work out the point on the SVG that I want to lock to the anchor point. In your SVG, I judge it to be about 80% down and 50% across. I transform the SVG element by these amounts in the upwards and backwards directions.

```
  /*  Anchor Point: (x: 100px, y: 50px) */
  .my-svg {
     position: absolute;
     left: 100px;
     top: 50px;
     transform: translate(-50%, -80%);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/n4v387uh/) is a JSFiddle demonstrating this.

As you can see, although the SVG changes size and moves around relative to the rest of the page (you can't really stop it!), the most interesting part of the SVG always stays more or less behind the main text, which is the effect I assume you are looking for.

Hardcoding the position of the text is probably not the best, but there are other ways you could do it. What matters is that you can position the top left corner of the SVG exactly on the anchor point. If the anchor point is the top left corner of an element, you could even make the SVG a child, or a sibling of this element, perhaps.

Comment: Yes! I'm so glad you've had the same problem I'm faced with; I was thinking along the same lines though with JS as I wasn't aware that CSS variables were natively supported in browsers (I thought that was exclusive to CSS supersets SASS/LESS).

I'll have a play with this in-situ and get back to you. I have a feeling that a larger than page width, absolutely positioned SVG will still ignore `overflow: hidden` which is a no-go for me but we'll see. I can't have width scrollbars because of the oversized SVG.